# angular 2 check if service is completed

Tags: angular, angular2-services

How can I check if a service is completed then run rest of the code?
example:
I want to get some data from API like this:

```ts
get_user_info(token: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.home + 'api/home/account/excerpt?token=' + token)
     .map((response: Response) => {
        return response.json().result;
     });
}
```

and I want to subscribe the data from `get_user_info`:

```ts
retrieve_user_info() {
    this.http.get_user_info(this.back_result.token).subscribe(
        (result: sendBackUserInfo) => {
            if (result.result == 1) {
                this.user_info = result.user;
            } else {
                console.log(result.messages[0]);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

but the problem is when I call the function `retrieve_user_info`, it doesn't get data immediately.
how can I fix that?

**EDIT:**
this is how I call `retrieve_user_info`:

```ts
submit_login_form() {
this.http.login_user(this.username, this.password, this.result.language.code)
    .subscribe((result: loginSendBackResult) => {
        this.back_result = result;
        this.retrieve_user_info();
        if (this.back_result.result == 1) {
            this.show_modal = false;
            console.log(user_info);
            router.navigate(['home']);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can't "fix this", this is asynchronous. Whatever you need to do to your data, you need to do it inside the callback :)

Comment: please show the code where you actually use that data. do you send it as `@Input()`to some component or what do you do with it?

Comment: @deezg the question has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)** to chain your requests. Also your naming made me a bit confused. When referring to service method, I would name the service something like `service` instead of `http` to separate where we are making a http-request and where we are calling a method in the service. So I used `service` here on those places instead.

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap";
```

```ts
submit_login_form() {
  this.service.login_user(...)
    .flatMap((result: loginSendBackResult) => {
        this.back_result = result;
        return this.retrieve_user_info();
    });
    .subscribe(data => {
        if(this.back_result.result == 1) { 
           console.log(this.user_info)
           ....
        }
    })
}
```

and your `retrieve_user_info()`

```ts
retrieve_user_info() {
  return this.service.get_user_info(this.back_result.token)
     .map((result: sendBackUserInfo) => {
        if (result.result == 1) {
           return this.user_info = result.user;
        } else {
           console.log(result.messages[0]);
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: You could also think of removing all "unnecessary logic" from the component to the service instead :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem with JS. You server is responding slower than you need it to. Where do you want this data? In the template or some other function. If you want it to be used in a template you can capture it using a function called as ngOnInit() which can be declared in the component class.

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

If its a different method. Please elaborate how and where you are calling the http request and why you need it immediately.

```
retrieve_user_info() {
    this.http.get_user_info(this.back_result.token).subscribe(
        (result: sendBackUserInfo) => {
            // Get both data in one request
            // Better your REST API
            // Do your checks with the dependent data
            // If dependent data right then change the router guard
            // https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate
            // Route the person using router
            // https://angular.io/api/router/Router
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I want to get data after a button is clicked! also that button is to login a user but I need some additional data from server before the user login process complete! I hope I could clearly explain my purpose

Comment: I still dont understand. Why do you to trigger two requests?

Comment: Use the edited logic. I dont know what additional data you need and whats it supposed to be. You will have to elaborate else you are un-understandable

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use:

```
subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, 
          error?: (error: any) => void, 
          complete?: () => void): Subscription;
```

The `complete?` part will only be performed when `next?` has successfully been completed so you can be sure the data has returned.

Comment: You don't need to, and probably don't want to, wait until the observable completes. You need only to wait until the `next` callback is called.